# Is it possible to nudge a div that is in the masterpage on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I need to have a page take a div that is in the masterpage and move it over like 300px to the right. Is this possible, and how? I figure it would be javascript or jquery. TIA

Comment: Which is your main concern? That you don't know how to move a div or that the div is in the master and not the page?

Comment: Or via a CSS override? In your page you could add inline CSS to the head (assuming you have a Section in the head to do so). The same would apply using jQuery/Javascript but you could put that anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery you can animate the div to move rather easily:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current_left = $("#myDiv").css('left');
    $("#myDiv").animate({
        "margin-left": "300px", // if #myDiv's position is relative
        "left": current_left + 300 + "px" // if #myDiv's position is absolute|fixed
    }, 400);
});
```

EDIT: The absolute was assuming to are using LEFT instead of RIGHT. The right would be:

```
"right": current_left - 300 + "px"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the div (with something like `document.getElementById()` or `getElementsByTagName()` or even `document.querySelector()`), then:

```
var elem = // some code to get the right div here
elem.style.position = "relative;
elem.style.left = "300px";
```

This will move the element 300 pixels to the right of its original position, however it won't work too well if the element already has a `position` other than `static`.